# How to fetch the value of an Interactive Grid radio button column in Dynamic Action on change?

Tags: radio-button, oracle-apex

I need to do some Client-side validation on a Radio button column in the Interactive Grid.

How could I get the selected value on change of the radio button in the dynamic action for an Interactive Grid?

I used the below code but it returns the object.

//Get the element that was clicked

var $te = $(this.triggeringElement);

//Get the ID of the row

var rowId = $te.closest('tr').data('id');

//Identify the particular interactive grid

var ig$ = apex.region("cisr").widget();

//Fetch the model for the interactive grid

var model = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model;

//Fetch the record for the particular rowId

var record = model.getRecord(rowId);

//Access the cell value via the column name

var sal = model.getValue(record,"AI_PCT_COMPLETED");

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the value attribute in your sal object, try this at the end of your code:

```
console.log(sal["v"]);
```